# Rails: creating a custom data type / creating a shorthand

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, code-generation, types, customization

I am wondering how I could create a custom data type to use within the rake migration file. Example: if you would be creating a model, inside the migration file you can add columns. It could look like this:

```
  def self.up
    create_table :products do |t|
      t.column :name, :string
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
```

I would like to know how to create something like this:

```
t.column :name, :my_custom_data_type
```

The reason for this to create for example a "currency" type, which is nothing more than a decimal with a precision of 8 and a scale of 2. Since I use only MySQL, the solution for this database is sufficient enough.

Thank you for your feedback and comments!

Comment: Using floating point data types for currency is generally a terrible idea.

Comment: If you have a better solution, please do elaborate.

Comment: Use something like the money gem, http://money.rubyforge.org/.

Comment: NSD: The question states that they're using decimal, not float.

Comment: theIV: The money gem doesn't help with migrations which is what Shyam is looking to simplify.

Comment: @theIV: I could use the money gem. But my question is how I could create a custom data type to use within the rake migration file.

Comment: @EmFi: I'm aware that the money gem doesn't help with migrations. My comment was more of a response to NSDs comment, in connection with Shyam's response. My apologies for not being on target with Shyam's original question.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

What you're looking to do is define a new column creation method that provides the options to create your custom type. Which is essentially done by adding a method that behaves like `t.integer ...` in migrations. The trick is figuring out where to add that code.

Some where in your initializers directory place this snippet of code:

```
module ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters
  class TableDefinition
    def currency (*args)
      options = args.extract_options!
      column_names = args
      options[:precision] ||= 8
      options[:scale] ||= 2
      column_names.each { |name| column(name, 'decimal', options) }
    end                                                                     
  end
end
```

Now you can use the currency method do define a currency column any time you need it.

Example:

```
def self.up
  create_table :products do |t|
    t.currency :cost
    t.timestamps
  end
end
```

To add a currency column to an existing table:

```
def self.up
  change_table :products do |t|
    t.currency :sell_price
  end
end
```

**Caveat:** I haven't time to test it, so there's no guarantees. If it doesn't work, it should at least put you on the right track.

Comment: I am going to test this right away. Thank you for the effort and your help!

Comment: Thanks, I just had a use for that. One thing to note: `t` is a `TableDefinition` in `create_table`, but a `Table` in `change_table`. I put my custom generation code into a module and included that in both of those classes.

Comment: Hi @emfi This is really good..Is there a way to take it further like having a Model currency? Just a thought because i want for e.g. for currency input validations at the same place also..I will also look for that..thanks

Comment: Currency validations are best done by stripping away everything but the decimal point and ensuring a numeric value. And formatting the currency only on display.