# creating a new column datatype in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, sqldatatypes

I might have not been searching for the right words in order to get an answer, so you were my last chance.

I am looking to create a new datatype in rails, for example:
t.israeli_id

which gets to pass a customized validation method, and adds errors according to it.

I will be using this datatype in several tables, so making it a string, and passing the validation function in each model.rb would be so much not DRY.

I am using Postgresql, just in case that would matter.

Comment: Also look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617447/rails-creating-a-custom-data-type-creating-a-shorthand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, you are approaching this in a wrong way. Database knows nothing about your application logic and it can only do basic validation (not null, etc.).

All of your application-specific validation, error messages and other stuff - it goes into your model. If you need that in several models and don't want duplicating the code, then create a model concern, `HasIsraeliId` or something. That's what concerns are for.

```
# app/models/concerns/has_israeli_id.rb
module HasIsraeliId
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    validate :some_field, whatever_condition: true
  end
end

# app/models/user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  include HasIsraeliId
end
```

Comment: I might have not explained it well, I want several models' columns be passed through a specific validation method, where do I put this validation method to be included in all models.rb ?

Comment: @KamalG'ool In this case, you create a [custom validator](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-validators) and assign it in your models. The validation logic won't be duplicated.

Comment: Post it as anwer with example to validate with any costum validation method name, and how include it in the model

Comment: @KamalG'ool: we don't do such requests on this site :)

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to be rude, I meant in order to select it as the correct answer :)

Comment: @KamalG'ool: no offense taken! Isn't the guide detailed enough to get you started, though?

Comment: @KamalG'ool: also, I think it _is_ a correct answer for the question pre-clarification :)